# An instance of sequence for (Monad m, Monoid a, Foldable t) => t (m a)?

Tags: haskell, monads

Given:

```
sequence :: (Monad m, Traversable t) => t (m a) -> m (t a)
sequence_ :: (Monad m, Foldable t) => t (m a) -> m ()
```

Want:

```
sequenceMonoid :: (Monad m, Foldable t, Monoid t1) => t (m t1) -> m t1
sequenceMonoid = foldr (\m m' -> do { x <- m; xs <- m'; return (x `mappend` xs) }) (return mempty)
```

To be clear a list only version should be definable as:

```
sequenceMonoid :: (Monad m, Monoid t1) => [m t1] -> m t1
sequenceMonoid x = mconcat <$> (sequence x)
```

Example usage:

```
sequenceMonoid [Just [1,2],Just [3,4]]
Just [1,2,3,4]
```

Would this definition be correct? If it is I would have expected this to be a common pattern that already existed somewhere in the existing Monoid libraries?

Comment: Your title indicates `Traversable`, your `sequenceMonoid` only `Foldable`. Which one do you want? Also, `sequenceMonoid` is `foldr (liftA2 mappend) (return mempty)`.

Comment: `foldMap id` is the generialized version of `mconcat` that works on all `Foldable`s. Your function can be defined as `\t -> foldMap id <$> sequence t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be the most succinct way to write what you want (and also indicates why, as a trivial composition, it isn't included directly in the libs).

```
> :t fmap fold . sequence
fmap fold . sequence :: (Monad f, Traversable t, Monoid b) => t (f b) -> f b
```

You can generalize `sequence` to `sequenceA` to get something even slightly more general.

```
> :t fmap fold . sequenceA
fmap fold . sequenceA :: (Applicative f, Traversable t, Monoid b) => t (f b) -> f b
```